# Creating Generic Segue in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Here how my storyboard looks like:

[image: Storyboard]

Initially when the users taps one of the squares, scene passes to the second one. At this point when the user closes the application and reopens it I want the second scene to come up.

I dont mind if first scene loads and then passes to the second one but I want second scene to show up.

Thanks in advance..

EDIT: I read that I can use generic segue but even if I create a generic segue with control drag from first view controller to the second one and using the code below nothing happens:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"switch" sender: self];
```

SOLUTION:

You got to have a navigation control :)

Comment: Where did you put [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"switch" sender: self]; ? What do you mean by "closes", just quit and resume or kill the app ?

Comment: Yes just quiting. But to make it simple, no need to check if it resumed or not. I just want to make this code work [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"switch" sender: self]; I put it in - (void)viewDidLoad of the first viewcontroller

Comment: I see you found your solution. I think you should post an answer to your question and accept it to show the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to user the code below:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"switch" sender: self];
```

You need to have a navigation control.